# Swift: How to add AVPlayerLayer to back layer of NSView

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsview, layer, avplayerlayer

I have an `NSView` in interface builder like so: 
 
[image: Set up]

I have buttons and a label inside the view (videoView) for playback control of a video. When I add an `AVPlayerLayer` (myPlayerLayer) to the view like so: 
`self.videoView.layer?.addSublayer(myPlayerLayer)` 
It adds the `AVPlayerLayer` as the top layer, thereby covering the buttons. How can I add the playerlayer to the back so it doesn't cover any of the other content?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try to use 'zPosition' property of `myPlayerLayer`?

Comment: @Astoria That did the trick! I had to set `zPosition = -1` though so it would go behind the buttons which were at `zPosition = 0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By doing: 
`myPlayerLayer.zPosition = -1`
I forced the `AVPlayerLayer` to be behind any other existing layers already in the `NSView`. Note that setting `zPosition` to `0` does not work; I believe the buttons and labels were at `0` and so I needed to go further back.